# Finding N elements in array whoes xor equals P

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinatorics, xor

I am working on a problem in which I am expected to find the number of combinations of `N<20` elements in array whose XOR equals `P`.

For example:
our array is {2 4 5 2 7}

1) if N=2 and P=6,

The answer is 2 (as we can choose only (2 xor 4) = 6 and (4 xor 2) = 6)

{**2** **4** 5 2 7} or {2 **4** 5 **2** 7}

2) if N=3 and P=6

The answer is 1 ((4 xor 5 xor 7) = 6)

The size of array can be really huge (something about 10^6) so I am looking for fast algorithm to solve that problem.

Comment: Are duplicate numbers allowed in the XOR? If not N can only be as large as the array.

Comment: Also, is there are language you are trying to do this in, and what have you tried already? A brute force solution is fairly simple.

Comment: Are the numbers themselves bounded?

Comment: Why do you think a fast algorithm exists? It isn't obvious that any polynomial time algorithm exists for it.

Comment: @cricket_007 There are no duplicates allowed in XOR and I haven't written it but N < 20. Of course I've tried brute force solution but it's just too slow as size of array can be 10^6.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm pretty sure that there is quite fast algorithm because this problem was given to my by my lecturer.

Comment: Finding all combinations of numbers in itself is far from fast

Comment: @Mark.: What is the source?

Comment: @cricket_007 Finding all combinations of numbers in itself is far from fast - that's right. But I'm not gonna finding those combinations by themselves. I only have to find number of them.

Comment: @coderredoc it's task given to my by me lecture.

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure you can convert this to a system of equations in Z_2 with integer coefficients.

Comment: You'll need to find them in order to XOR them and check for equality, I think, though, right? Unless there is some fancy bit manipulation magic that I'm overlooking

Comment: Following up on what @JohnColeman said, this problem is *at best* fixed-parameter tractable, since removing the limit on N allows an easy reduction from a canonical #P-complete problem (counting perfect matchings). VtC too broad anyway because homework.

Comment: @cricket_007 that would be easiest solution but it's definitely too slow to check XOR of over 10^6 choose 20 sets of numbers. There must be something more optimal.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, good point.

Comment: So, fun fact, 6 xor (2 xor 4) = 0 and 6 xor (4 xor (5 xor 7)) = 0. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, I'v chosen P=6 on purpose because (((2 xor 4) xor 5) xor 2) xor 7 = 6. That's why 6 xor (2 xor 4) = 0 and 6 xor (4 xor (5 xor 7)) = 0. But I have no idea how to use this fact to make my solution faster

Comment: I was thinking maybe you could do something N times to the array using P that would cause certain elements to zero out, then scan over the array and count the number of zeroes...

Comment: Are there any further constaints about the elements of the array (e.g. whether the values in the array are always between 0 and a certain maximum value)?

Comment: @Marco13 Yes, they are always between 0 and 10^6

Comment: Have there been any hints (maybe just by the title of some slide in this lecture...) that the way to solve this is related to **dynamic programming** ?

Comment: @Marco13 unfortunately no. I was only told that this is interesting problem and it's worth spending some time to find a solution, now I'm really curious

Answer (score 1):

EDIT not working because N is fixed

Using linear algebra:

As suggested by @blazs, you can view P and each number of your array as vectors in a Z/2Z vector space. What's more, since XOR is associative and commutative, you're not looking for combinations of elements of your array, but *sets* of these elements, and a set can also be encoded as a Z/2Z vector.

So you'll end up with a matrix equation like M*S=P, where P is the xor-sum in Z/2Z vector format, M is the matrix which columns are the elements of the array in Z/2Z format , and S is the unknown of the equation.

Since you're only interested in the size of the solution space, all you need to do is find the *dimension* of the solution space, and then raise 2 to the power of it.

Comment: I posted and deleted this answer two hours ago. It doesn't work because N, the number of elements in the subset, is fixed.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, I think you can set it as a system of equations Ax=y while requiring ||x||^2 = N? (I haven't worked it out though... I might try to do so later today.)

Comment: @blazs we're not in an R-based vector space here

Comment: You mean that ||x|| might not be well-defined? It doesn't matter, what I meant by ||x|| is that the sum of its elements be equal to k, i.e., that it contains exactly k ones. I think once you add this constraint the problems become equivalent.

Comment: Ah, yes... you have a point. It seems it's nothing more than a restatement... you don't get to use any nice tools from linear algebra.

Comment: one would need to find (generate) a linear application f and a constant vector C such that fS=C iff the support of S has cardinality N, I don't know if that's possible

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck, by the way, I wrote about the problem in more detail [here](http://sovdatb.blogspot.si/2015/11/an-algorithmic-problem.html).

Comment: I confirm that it's not possible.

Comment: @Mark then what is the problem?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck It's not a problem, it's just additional assumption that can make it (or not) less complicated. Just wondering ;)

Comment: Ah you mean if you remove the N-elements constraint?

Comment: No, if I remove N-elements constraint then I'm able to count number of subsets in O(size of array*P). I mean that we can set variable P to constant value that equals xor of all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed recursive algorithm, may be faster than brute force:

Find some bit of P which is 1. Any solution combination must contain at least one number which has a 1 in that bit.

For each element K of the array which has a 1 at that bit, recur with:

- P' = P xor K *(xor - substraction)*
- arr' = arr - {set of J in arr which have a 1 in that bit, and which index is less than or equal to K} *(because we're assuming K is the first element of the combination with a 1 at this position in the solution space)*
- N = N - 1

Termination cases:

- if P=0, and N=0, one solution
- if N=0 and P!=0, no solution
- if arr is empty, no solution
- if there's a bit where P has a 1 and no element of arr does, no solution

Note that XOR is associative and commutative, so we're counting sets, not combinations.

Comment: I also tried a recursive approach similar to this one, e.g. with the same basic termination case - however, I'm not sure about the second step, and the fact that you are refering to *bits* here. Note that each bit is *set* by including an **odd** number of elements that contain this bit, and each bit is *cleared* by including an **even** number of elements that contain this bit. I'm not sure whether this is still covered here....